# How to prove the: $ \int_{\mathbb R^n}\exp(-\frac{|w|^2}{2}) |w-v|^{a} dw\sim (1+|v|^2)^{a/2} $

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a>-n$ where $a\in\mathbb R$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. How to show that
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}\exp(-\frac{|w|^2}{2}) |w-v|^{a} dw\sim (1+|v|^2)^{a/2} 
$$
for all $v\in\mathbb R^n$?

Some cases is trivial:
If $a=0$ then it holds.

If $a>0$ then "$\leq $" holds by $|w-v|^a \leq |w|^a + |v|^a \leq (|w|^a+1)(1+|v|^2)^{a/2}$ and so integrating both sides yields "$\leq$". But for "$\geq$", It is not clear to me why obtaining.

Similarly, for $a<0$.

Comment: what to you mean by 'for all $v$'?

Comment: Hi, i mean that there are constants $c_1, c_2>0$ such that $LHS\leq c_1 RHS \leq c_2 LHS$ for all $v$. Here LHS is left hand side and RHS is right hand side

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider the case where $-n<-n+2\epsilon=a<0.$ If $Z\sim N(0,I_n)$ consider the random variable $(Z-v)/\sqrt{1+v^2}=Z\cos \theta-u\sin \theta$, by  denoting $v=u\tan \theta$ where $\|u\|^2=1.$

We write
$$\theta \mapsto I(\theta)=E(\|Z\cos \theta-u\sin\theta\|^{-n+2\epsilon})=\int_{0}^{\infty}E\left(e^{-s\|Z\cos \theta-u\sin\theta\|^2}\right)\frac{s^{\frac{n}{2}-\epsilon-1}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\epsilon)}ds$$ The task is to show that there exist two numbers $c_1$ and $c_2$ depending on $\epsilon$ such that for all $\theta$ one has $c_1<I(\theta)<c_2.$

A computation gives $$E\left(e^{-s\|Z\cos \theta-u\sin\theta\|^2}\right)=\frac{1}{(1+s\cos^2\theta)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\frac{s\sin^2\theta}{1+s\cos^2\theta}\right)=f(s,\theta)$$
Now denoting $$k(t)=-\log f(s,\theta)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{s(1-t)}{1+st}+\frac{1}{2}\log(1+st)$$ with $t=\cos^2\theta,$ a painful and elementary calculation of the max and the min of $k(t)$ on $0<t<1$ shows that for all $0<t<1$ we have

1. either $s<n-1$ and $\frac{s}{2}<k(t)<\frac{n}{2}\log(1+s)$
2. or $s>n-1$ and $ C_n+\frac{n}{2}\log(1+s))<k(t)<\max (\frac{s}{2},\frac{n}{2}\log(1+s)),$ with $C_n=\frac{1}{2}(n-1)-\frac{n}{2}\log n.$

Denoting $m(s)=\min_{\theta}f(s,\theta)$ and $M(s)=\max_{\theta}f(s,\theta)$ we get $$c_1=\int_{0}^{\infty}m(s)\frac{s^{\frac{n}{2}-\epsilon-1}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\epsilon)}ds >0 ,\ \ \  c_2=\int_{0}^{\infty}M(s)\frac{s^{\frac{n}{2}-\epsilon-1}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}-\epsilon)}ds<\infty.$$

Comment: wonderful. thanks for your answer

Comment: Thanks. This interesting question can be seen as a property of the non central chi square distribution. What is its source?